# launch an application programmatically after installation in android

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have developed an application(Test)such that whenever the application has updates with the latest version it will download and install the latest .apk file.

Now I want the latest version of application to launch/open by itself after updating. For now I am manually launching the application after update. I want it to do by itself.

Please Help..

Thanks

Comment: Let the Play Store handle the updates...

Comment: I am not placing my app in play store. This is a non market app..!!!!.

Comment: So why do you bother to update it? Or, since you will have 4 or 5 users, just send them the new apk via eMail.

Comment: Thats not the standard way i believe. I cannot count on my users. I am working for a product. There may be n number of users

Comment: Hello @ShrutiJoshi did you got any success with it,?
I am also looking for the same functionality for my app.
I believe when you install an apk, you need to start it once to register it in Android System. and thn all your recivers become active.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Android throws broadcast on installing app . You could receive it in receiver and launch from there.

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.your.receiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
                    <data android:scheme="package"/> 
                </intent-filter>
     </receiver>

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_PACKAGE_REMOVED" />
```

In receiver add this :

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //start activity
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.setClassName("com.pkg", "com.pkg.yourStartActivity");
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, and i managed to relaunch my app after i reinstalled programatically. That was 2 month ago. Now i switched to android 8 and its not working... Is that related? Or maybe i missing something?

Comment: @MosheYamini Were you missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the intent filter you have to set for your broadCastReceiver

```
 <receiver android:name="com.your.receiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```