# How to launch an app automatically after using adb sideload it?

Tags: java, android

I have built an Android system service app. It does not have any activity to run. But right now, if I want to start the app, I have to give the device admin to the app and then reboot the device so that it will start. Could anyone please give me some hints how can I launch the app automatically after side load the app? I followed the answers in this post but doesnt work:
[launch an application programmatically after installation in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35426429/launch-an-application-programmatically-after-installation-in-android)
Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to start and stop android service from a adb shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7415997/how-to-start-and-stop-android-service-from-a-adb-shell)

Comment: Rakibul, I have tried that using the adb command to start service. But I still need to do a reboot after the adb command. Do you know why?